# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError on machine without Java installed

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a Java program on a machine that doesn't have Java installed, but instead JAVA_HOME is set to a network location, where Java is installed. When I'm trying to run the program I get `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError`, even though I tried with JDK 1.7 and 1.6jdk. It's actually a Jersey web appliacation.

Comment: If I run `java -version` I get `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. As I said , java is not istalled on this machine, but I'm using it from a network location.

Comment: did you check whether that program runs fine in the machine where java is installed. i'd suggest to first run it on machine where java is installed first.

Comment: Then, how do you start your Java program, if "java" is not recognized as a command?

Comment: Yes, It runs fine. Could it be from my Tomcat?

Comment: Additionally, the UnsupportedClassVersionError just means, that you are using a JRE6 loading a class that was compiled with JDK7.

Answer (score 0):

You get this issue because you try to run the  program with a different version than the one used to compile it. In the error message, you should get a number. Please find below the mapping between this number and the version you should use to run the program:

51 → Java 7

50 → Java 6

49 → Java 5.0

48 → Java 1.4

47 → Java2 1.3

46 → Java2 1.2

45 → Java 1.1

Comment: I get 51 but I set JAVA_HOME to a JDK Version 1.7.0_11 and nothing.

Comment: What about your PATH ? Could you paste the value of the environment variable ?

Comment: Just setting `JAVA_HOME` does not work. Java itself does not look at the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Make sure you run the `java` command from the right Java version.